# 10 Inserts by 10 Threads at the same time in Azure table storage using c#

Tags: c#, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

What will happen if I get responses from 10 threads and few of them simultaneously or at the same time, try to insert the responses in the table located in azure table storage. Will it break or throw error? If yes, how to handle that in c#?

Comment: Have you already tried it? It really depends of the data. If they have no overlapping PK/RK combinations there won't be a problem. Otherwise you might get conflicts you have to resolve.

Comment: Peter is correct. Regarding the details of concurrency control, I'd suggest you to read the blog post: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/managing-concurrency-in-microsoft-azure-storage-2/

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the azure table storage will not catch how many threads you have used now to insert the value to the table.

It will just catch the throughput of the table storage.

Mainly this target:

```
Maximum request rate per storage account Tables: 20,000 transactions per second (assuming 1 KB entity size)

Target throughput for single table partition (1 KB entities): Up to 2000 entities per second
```

So if your application doesn't exceed the table storage throughput limit. It will not return error.

If you have exceed the table storage throughput limit, you could use try catch to catch the exception and insert the data later.

Besides, as  Zhaoxing Lu says, you need consider more about concurrency, more details, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-concurrency#managing-concurrency-in-the-table-service).